# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I am developing a web application with String framework using Eclipse and  Tomcat Server 7. I keep getting the same error when I run it:

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /views/misc/index.jsp at line 19

Line 19 is: `<jsp:forward page="/welcome/index.do" />`

Sometimes it works when I keep refreshing the page, but I don't know why.

**misc/index.jsp**

```
<%--
 * index.jsp

 --%>

<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@taglib prefix="jstl" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>

<jsp:forward page="/welcome/index.do" />
```

This is the index.jsp page of the welcome view

```
<%--
 * index.jsp
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2014 Universidad de Sevilla
 * 
 * The use of this project is hereby constrained to the conditions of the 
 * TDG Licence, a copy of which you may download from 
 * http://www.tdg-seville.info/License.html
 --%>

<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@taglib prefix="jstl" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>

<p><spring:message code="welcome.greeting.prefix" /><spring:message code="welcome.greeting.suffix" /></p>

<p><spring:message code="welcome.greeting.current.time" /> ${moment}</p>
```

Stacktrace:

```
> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page
> /views/misc/index.jsp at line 19
> 
> type Exception report
> 
> message An exception occurred processing JSP page
> /views/misc/index.jsp at line 19:
 <jsp:forward page="/welcome/index.do" />
> 
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
> from fulfilling this request.
> 
> exception
> 
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
> JSP page /views/misc/index.jsp at line 19
> 
> 16: <%@taglib prefix="security"
> uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%> 17: <%@taglib
> prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%> 18:  19:
> <jsp:forward page="/welcome/index.do" />
> 
> 
> Stacktrace:
>   
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Root cause:

```
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.views.misc.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

`

Comment: Please copy paste line 19 in your question

Comment: Where /welcome/index.do resides I mean in jar file or ??

Comment: Is that the ***complete*** stack trace? Where are the "caused by" sections?

Comment: The welcome view is in a folder and it contains the index that is a jsp file

Comment: I'll include the root cause in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in  jsp:forward. Use  index.jsp instead of  index.do in that tag

Comment: I tried it but then I get error:  HTTP Status 404 - /AcmeSupermarket/welcome/index.jsp

Comment: @Kaoutar Ben Moussa and that's much more better error ) you should put your index.jsp in welcome folder , I guess it is not there, or chande url from /AcmeSupermarket/welcome to the path where your index.jsp you want to redirect to is located.